# laravel join and where condition on two tables with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

### I have this:

**Products**

```
+--------------+--------------+
| id  | name   | description  |
+--------------+--------------+
| 1   | shirt  |  some desc   |
| 2   | shirt_b|  some desc   |
| 3   | shoe   |  some desc   |
| 4   | shirt_c|  some desc   |
+--------------+--------------+
```

**Product_metas**

```
--------------+---------+--------+
| product_id  |  color  |  price |
--------------+---------+--------+
|      1      |  black  |  2000  |
|      1      |  red    |  6000  |
|      1      |  brown  |  8000  |
|      2      |  black  |  6000  |
|      2      |  green  |  4000  |
|      3      |  blue   |  7000  |
|      4      |  red    |  9000  |
|      4      |  blue   |  2000  |
|      4      |  black  |  8000  |
--------------+--------+---------+
```

user wants to search with **product name** and **price range** like this :
keyword : "shirt"  , min-price: "5000", max-price: "10000"

#### and result of this search should be like this (with pagination):

```
[
    0 : [
            Name : shirt
            Desc : some desc
            metas [
                0 : [red   , 6000],
                1 : [brown , 8000],
            ]
        ],
    1 : [
            Name : shirt_b
            Desc : some desc
            metas [
                0 : [black   , 6000],
            ]
        ],
    2 : [
            Name : shirt_c
            Desc : some desc
            metas [
                0 : [red     , 9000],
                1 : [black   , 8000],
            ]
        ],
]
```

#### Controller:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('keyword') . '%')
    ->whereHas('metas', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereBetween('price', [
            $request->input('price_min'),
            $request->input('price_max')
        ]);
    })
    ->paginate(10);

return view('/home' , compact(['products']));
```

#### view:

```
<div>
    {!! $products->render() !!}
    @forelse($products as $product)
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Name : </strong>{{ $product->name }}</li>
            <li><strong>Desc : </strong>{{ $product->desc }}</li>
            <ul>
                @forelse($product->metas()->get() as $meta)
                    <li><strong>Color : </strong>{{ $meta->color }}<strong> --> $ </strong>{{ $meta->price }}</li>
                @empty
                    <h3>no meta</h3>
                @endforelse
            </ul>
        </ul>
    @empty
        <h3>no data</h3>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

how i should query in controller and show them in view with pagination ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried everything in hours... no luck

Comment: You need to show us what you tried and the result/errors you get. We're here to help you sort out issues in your code, not to do all the work for you (which we would need since we have no code to go on)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok i put the controller code and view side in question, i'm new with laravel and have no idea what should i do, sorry.

Comment: whereHas just checks if products has any related rows, its a condition. It doesnt fetch data from another table. Use with instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, `whereHas` just filters results based on the callback. But the rest of the comment was wrong. To include the values from the other table, use `with` *as well as* `whereHas`, not instead of it.

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
    ->whereHas('metas', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereBetween('price', [$request->price_min, $request->price_max]);
    })
    ->with('metas')
    ->paginate(10);

return view('/home' , compact('products'));
```

Assuming your `Product` and `Meta` models have proper relationships, this will generate the following SQL queries, returning the results you want:

```
select * from `products` where `name` like '%shirt%' and exists (select * from `product_metas` where `products`.`id` = `product_metas`.`product_id` and `price` between 5000 and 1000);
select * from `product_metas` where `product_metas`.`product_id` in (1, 2, 4)
```

Not ideal that it runs two queries, but that's Laravel.

In your layout, no need to use the relation method. Just use the property instead:

```
@forelse($product->metas as $meta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define models and raletions. In Products model:

```
        public function metas(){       
            return $this->hasMany('ProductMetas');
        }
```

Then

```
$products = Products::with('metas')->where('name',$name)->where('price','=>', $LB)->where('price','<=',$UB)->simplePaginate(15);
return View::make('view.name', compact('products'));
```

Remember to get name, and price bounds from input.

Comment: i did and now it's showing this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price' in 'where clause'

Comment: delete wheres and check what data you get. It may be the relation is wrong. Plus, check again your ProductMeta model, do you have price field in your protected $fillable = array(..., 'price'); ?

Comment: yes i copied your code and replace variables , and double check both Models for proper relation and also both models has fillabe.

Comment: the thing is, query should return multiple products and each product has multiple color and each color has price